# How to transparent background when pushViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

how to transparent background when pushViewcontroller??
just like.. modal view over full screen
 (programmatically, not using storyboard, not using present modal)

---

first view controller > Button Action >

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type =  kCATransitionPush //kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFade

    self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

    let testVC = SecondViewController()

    if let existVC = self.navigationController {
        existVC.pushViewController(testVC, animated: false)
    }
```

---

second View Controller

```
super.viewDidLoad()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

The result is... black background.
how to transparent background??

Comment: Just use present view controller instead of push

Comment: Hacking the animation of `UINavigationController` never works reliably. The controller is replaced there, therefore you cannot achieve transparency.